# How to properly typeset this table-like paragraph?

Tags: tables, paragraphs

I would like to typeset the following paragraph:

[image]

What I can achieve so far is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,csquotes,tabularx}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
    \( \mathbb{N} \): & set of natural numbers \( (0, 1, 2, \cdots, n, \cdots) \) (N for \textquote{numbers}).\\
    \( \mathbb{Z} \): & ring of rational integers (natural numbers and their negatives) (Z for \textquote{Zahlen}).\\
    \( \mathbb{Q} \): & field of rational numbers (quotients of elements of \( \mathbb{Z} \)) (Q for \textquote{quotients}).\\
    \( \mathbb{R} \): & field of real numbers (R for \textquote{reals}).\\
    \( \mathbb{C} \): & field of complex numbers (C for \textquote{complexes}).\\
    \( \mathbb{F}_q \): & finite field with \( q \) elements (F for \textquote{finite} or \textquote{field}).
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But I don't know how to put the parentheses in new lines and make them vertically aligned.

Also, it doesn't have to be a table, since by making it a table the content shall become unbreakable (unless using `longtable`, but then the width cannot be simply set as with `tabularx`). I've also tried `description` but the result is not so good (the alignment is different).

How should one properly typeset the content to get the original result?

Comment: `\newline\hspace*{2em}(F for ...` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for this! By the way, do you also know how to reduce the spacing between the two columns?

Comment: `l@{}X` or `l@{\hspace{3pt}}X` or ....

Comment: It is better to set in `\begin{description}\item[$\mathbb{N}$]...\end{description}`, my thought...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution but without using a table which adds indentation if the text is long. See [`\makebox[][]{}`](http://latexref.xyz/_005cmbox-_0026-_005cmakebox.html) if you prefer a different horizontal alignment; `makebox` accepts either `[l]`, `[c]` or `[r]` as the second optional argument.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,csquotes}

\newcommand\setdescr[2]{%
    \hangindent=4.5em%
    \hangafter=1%
    \noindent\makebox[2.5em][r]{\ensuremath{#1}:}\hspace{1em}#2\par}

\usepackage{showframe}


\begin{document}
\setdescr{\mathbb{N}}{set of natural numbers \( (0, 1, 2, \cdots, n, \cdots) \)\newline%
    (N for \textquote{numbers}).}
\setdescr{\mathbb{Z}}{ring of rational integers (natural numbers and their negatives)\newline%
    (Z for \textquote{Zahlen}).}
\setdescr{\mathbb{Q}}{field of rational numbers (quotients of elements of \( \mathbb{Z} \))\newline%
    (Q for \textquote{quotients}).}
\setdescr{\mathbb{R}}{field of real numbers\newline%
    (R for \textquote{reals}).}
\setdescr{\mathbb{C}}{field of complex numbers\newline%
    (C for \textquote{complexes}).}
\setdescr{\mathbb{F}_q}{finite field with \( q \) elements\newline%
    (F for \textquote{finite} or \textquote{field}).}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amssymb,csquotes,tabularx}

    \begin{document}

    \noindent
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
        \( \mathbb{N} \): & set of natural numbers \( (0, 1, 2, \cdots, n, \cdots) \)\par\quad (N for \textquote{numbers}).\\
        \( \mathbb{Z} \): & ring of rational integers\par\quad (natural numbers and their negatives) (Z for \textquote{Zahlen}).\\
        \( \mathbb{Q} \): & field of rational numbers\par\quad (quotients of elements of \( \mathbb{Z} \)) (Q for \textquote{quotients}).\\
        \( \mathbb{R} \): & field of real numbers\par\quad (R for \textquote{reals}).\\
        \( \mathbb{C} \): & field of complex numbers\par\quad (C for \textquote{complexes}).\\
        \( \mathbb{F}_q \): & finite field with \( q \) elements\par\quad (F for \textquote{finite} or \textquote{field}).
    \end{tabularx}

    \end{document}
```

[image]